# How do you add custom logo to entire themes

Tags: plugins

I would like to add a custom logo to my entire blog network's dashboard. I went trough a recipe on smashing magazine and got this code:

```
//hook the administrative header output
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');

function my_custom_logo() {
    echo '
      <style type="text/css">
      #header-logo { background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/custom-logo.gif) !important; }
      </style>
    ';
 }
```

Where do I add it? I think that I should add it in `functions.php`. But if so I should add the code to every theme in my mutlinetworks.

Does any one have idea to add it to the entire network?
I should also able to set only  for a particular sub and not to entire network If I change my mind in future :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this logo to show up across your network sites regardless of the theme I'd advise you to create a new PHP file inside `wp-content/mu-plugins` (create the directory if it doesn't exist) and drop that code inside the new file. You can name your file whatever you like - for example `my-network-tweaks.php`. That file will be loaded automatically as a plugin on all of the sites.

And if you'd like to override this image for a particular site you can make that function pluggable. Like this:

```
<?php
//hook the administrative header output
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');

// if override function exists load it up instead
if(function_exists('override_my_custom_logo')) {

    function my_custom_logo() {
        override_my_custom_logo();
    }

// fallback to original function
} else {

    function my_custom_logo() {
        echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #header-logo { background-image: url('/path/to/images/custom-logo.gif) !important; }
        </style>
        ';
    }

}
?>
```

Note that I've changed the image path because we want it to point to a single file for the whole network. Using `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` would cause it to load the image from the theme directory.

If you want to override the image for a single site, just use Tom J Nowell's code renaming the function to `override_my_custom_logo`

Comment: As I understand ...I need to copy the code given by Tom and place it in a new file custom_logo_for_entire_site.php under plugins .
ANd I need to use replace the image path given in Tom's code using ('/path/to/images/custom-logo.gif') .Where do I need to keep the logo image? Do I need to create a new images folder under the /wpcontent ?

Comment: Put the file in `wp-content/mu-plugins`, not in the regular `wp-content/plugins` forlder. The image path is totally your choice - you can put the image for example inside `wp-content/uploads`(main blog uploads folder) and then the path to it will be `get_bloginfo('wpurl') . /wp-content/uploads/custom-logo.gif'`

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the [White Label CMS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/white-label-cms/) plugin to automate this for you.

Comment: That plugin looks great. Wish I'd known about it years ago!

Comment: We can add logo and use the plugin to white label.But I would like to know that how do I use the additional functions like adding widgets to dash board,changing default gravator ,adding and removing default profile fields etc using functions.php .We may have all these functionalities with different plugins. But I came to know that there are some tricks to add the functionalities using functions.php .So that we can also save our site from high page loading speed caused by plugins.
So could you help me If I can add this kind codes using functions.php to all the themes ?

Answer (score 1):

Place this in functions.php and add a file custom-logo.gif ( 32x32 pixels ) in an images subfolder of your theme.

```
//hook the administrative header output
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');

function my_custom_logo() {
    echo '
<style type="text/css">
#header-logo { background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/custom-logo.gif) !important; }
</style>
';
}
```